# how to add developers list in pom.xml file.whenever the build fails it will send notifications

Tags: jenkins, pom.xml

presently i am using jenkins for continous integration i configured poll scm for 45 minutes.whenever the build fails it is sending failure notification to developers. Now i want in pom.xml to configure developers list. from here the jenkins should read and send failure notification who commit the code that person only should get failure notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a plugin called "email-ext"
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Once installed, in the post-build actions, checkmark "Editable Email Notification"
Then, you have a choice of "triggers", for example "Fixed" or "Failure" or "Success", and checkmarks that let you select whom to send the email to for every trigger.

You have the option of sending to:
Recipient list - predefined list, either global or per trigger
Committers - those that made SVN changes for this checkout
Culprits - those that made SVN changes since last successful build
Requester - user that triggers the build

In your particular case, you would want a "Failure" trigger, and send email only to "Committers" and possibly "Culprits", and don't checkmark Recipient list.

Comment: @slav As I understand, that is not really what phanikumar Raja asked for. As I understand "Commiters" and "Culprits" only looks at the actual commiters in CVS. It does *not* look at the developers information in the pom.xml. Am I right here? Am also looking for a solution that utilitzes the developers information from the POM.