# how to send mail to developers about build status

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I would like to send build status mail after maven build. I configured in `pom.xml`.

```
<developers>
<developer>
<id>phani</id>
<name>phanikumar</>
<email>phanikumarraja@yahoo.com</email>
<url>http://phani.net</url>
<organization>codeauroara</organization>
<organizationurl>http:/mojocodeaurora.org</organizationurl>
<roles>
<role>Lead</role>
<role>developer</role>
</roles>
</developer>
</developers>
```

Presently, I am using jenkins for automate build it is sending mail suppose build fails.
I want to do jenkins should read in `pom.xml` file those who are in developers list of `pom.xml` file.
for those members only send mail through jenkins about build status.

Please tell me if any plugin required for this or if I need to configure any mailing lists in `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could first look at the Jenkins's [Mail Server Configuration](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/ide/9781449311155/configuring-your-jenkins-server/sect-configuration-email) and at [Email Notification](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/ide/9781449311155/notification/sect-notification-email) in the job's configuration.

You could also use a Jenkins plugin : *[email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)* to perform more advanced tasks.

See also this SO answer : *[how to add developers list in pom.xml file.whenever the build fails it will send notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13031975/1677594)*

Comment: Your answer doesn't help. None of your suggestions utilizes the developers information from the pom. The SO answer you refer to doesn't help either.